# repeat testcase in Boost test multiple times

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

Is there a way to repeatedly run a unit-test or a set of unit-tests in Boost test?

Let say I have the following:

```
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(someSuite, someFixture)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(someTest)
{
    ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

... and I'd like to run `someTest` with setup/teardown for let say 100 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run your test program in a loop. I do not believe there is test case/suite level feature to do this now. Feel free to request one through the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

According to [boost config](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/runtime_config/summary.html) there is no option to specify multiple times execution.

It is possible to use some Linux commands like:

```
for i in `seq 10`; do command; done
```

Comment: This type of approach won't be suited when you want the command to generate a single report (e.g. JUnit). You'd have to strap together multiple reports into one.